# Why won't this object-oriented OpenGL code draw a triangle, but the expanded version does?

Tags: c++

> The code is too long to put on Stack Overflow, so I put it in a [Gist](https://gist.github.com/BlueStaggo/e021ddb0d5bda87f403a454a184dc3d9). To use the code, you need to use only one of the main.cpp files.

I am learning from [learnopengl.com](https://learnopengl.com) and I am at the point where I draw the triangle. However, my Object Oriented code does not draw the triangle. When I expanded my code (like macros, e.g. expanding `ADD(x, y)` to `x + y` when `#define ADD(x, y) x + y`), the code worked. In fact, every time I tried to object orient OpenGL, it always failed. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Log every GL call. Then compare logs before and after OOP-fication.

Comment: `vertices` decays to pointer to float when you pass it as `float vertices[]` to function. So `sizeof(vertices)` returns a size of pointer to float instead the whole size of data for your triangle. Pass additional parameter which stores the actual size of passed data.

Comment: Can you tell if the OOP code opens the window and compiles shaders correctly? So to narrow down the problem. My suggestion here is to check the GL calls order.

Comment: Does `glfwCreateWindow` return an `unsigned int`  (as in `id` in globj.h)? Becuase it seems to me that it returns a `GLFWwindow*` as in `window`  in main-exp.cpp, Seems strange to me that you wrote `id = glfwCreateWindow(...)`  I'm surprised your compiler didn't complain.

Comment: Surprising to me that you would call `glfwCreateWindow` before calling `glfwInit`, especially since `glfwCreateWindow` lists `GLFW_NOT_INITIALIZED` as one of its potential error codes ([see docs](https://www.glfw.org/docs/3.3/group__window.html#ga5c336fddf2cbb5b92f65f10fb6043344))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure about other problems, but this is definitely wrong:

```cpp
    inline static void data(float vertices[],
                            GLenum usage = GL_STATIC_DRAW)
    { glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, usage); }

    inline static void data(const float vertices[],
                            GLenum usage = GL_STATIC_DRAW)
    { glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, usage); }
```

`sizeof(vertices)` will always be `sizeof(float*)` because that's how C arrays work – they don't carry information about their length when passed as arguments. In `main-exp.cpp` you're doing `sizeof` on the constexpr, which does count the items. Fix this by any of these methods which should replace `sizeof(vertices)`:

- use `std:vector`, `std:array` or (C++20) `std:span`.
- explicitly pass the length alongside of the C array.

Comment: the sizeof seems definitely the error here, since your OpenGL will be loading the wrong data. the sizeof in the non OOP code instead works correctly because the sizeof of a fixed size array at compiletime will be as you expected it. passing instead it to a function will be seen as a normal pointer.